# How to pull ACF values into a custom post type archive

Tags: php, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

So my issue is that I just created a custom post type and have created a couple of posts to go along with this. I am using ACF fields in the template single-post_type.php That I created. These show up fine on the individual posts, but I need some of the ACF field values that are on the individual post page to show up on the custom post index. I've tried searching for answers but just can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

For reference, Here is the code I have registering the custom post type:

```
// Add new post type for Available Homes
add_action('init', 'available_homes');
function available_homes() 
{
$available_homes_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Available Homes', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Available Home', 'post type singular name'),
    'all_items' => __('All Available Homes'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Listing', 'recipes'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Listing'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Listing'),
    'new_item' => __('New Listing'),
    'view_item' => __('View Listing'),
    'search_items' => __('Search in Available Homes'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No listings found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No listings found in trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $available_homes_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
    'has_archive'  =>  'available_homes'
); 
register_post_type('available_homes',$args);
}
```

And I have some basic ACF fields on single-available_homes.php

Then I have a page called archive-available_homes.php which has this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<h1 class="page-title">Available Homes</h1>
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts('') ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );     ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing   Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were   found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<div class="widget_area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar("gravity_form_widget_area"); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

ACF Fields and everything else is working fine on the individual posts but I just don't know what to do to get the ACF field data to show on the archive page. Help?

Answer (score 2):

ACF Fields must be in the loop. Your `archive-available_homes.php` file doesn't have a loop, it calls

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );     ?>
```

So it's in content.php you have to add your field you want to render.
Otherwise, you can create your own `content-available_homes.php` file and call :

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'available_homes' );     ?>
```

Comment: This is the answer. Note that if you want some specific options for your archive page, one option you have is to create ACF option pages (available in PRO). https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Answer (score 2):

U can use my plugin `ACF CPT Options Pages`

[Download here](https://github.com/Tusko/ACF-CPT-Options-Pages)

Comment: You should submit this as an add-on for ACF. This could help out lots of people! 

EDIT: And literally right after I posted this, changed tabs, scrolled down and then saw it on the add-on listing page....

Comment: now it's on here https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-cpt-options-pages/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into how to post fields from other pages here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

This may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**2020** - I've done it in few minutes with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-archive/